# Angularjs - Md-select breaks when in a ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-material

For some reason when I try to add a md-select in a ng-repeat it starts giving me the errors. Here is a quick example of what im trying to accomplish:

```
App.controller('Forumlaire_Controller', function ($scope, Shared_Service) {

    $scope.Parent_Data = [{Name:"Bob", Selection: "1"},{Name:"Rick", Selection: "2"},{Name:"Lori", Selection: "3"} ];
    $scope.selections = [{1: "Option1",2: "Option 2",3: "Option 4",4: "Option 5",5: "Option 6"}]

})
```

In the example below I get the error

> "[ngRepeat:iexp]" expected expression in form of '*item* in *collection*[ track by *id*]':

```
<div ng-repeat="parent for Parent_Data">
    <md-input-container style="margin-top: 5px; margin-bottom: 5px;" flex="25">
        <label>État</label>
        <md-select ng-model="Example">
        <md-option ng-repeat="item for selections" ng-value="item"> {{item}} </md-option>
        </md-select>
    </md-input-container>   
</div>
```

I tried the following, I dont get errors anymore but I cant select anything. Selection is stuck on the first option:

```
<div ng-repeat="parent for Parent_Data">    
    <md-input-container style="margin-top: 5px; margin-bottom: 5px;" flex="25">
        <label>État</label>
        <md-select ng-model="Example" ng-model-options="{ trackBy: '$index' }">
        <md-option ng-repeat="item in selections" ng-value="item"> {{item}} </md-option>
        </md-select>
    </md-input-container>   
</div>
```

Does any one understand what the problem is?

Comment: `ng-repeat="item for selections"` is illegal syntax.

Comment: Follow the "best practice" of always have a '.' in your ng-models.

Comment: `$scope.selections` has only one item in its array, so of course it is only going to show one option.

Comment: The `ng-model-options` directive doesn't have a `trackBy` option.

Comment: Start by reading [AngularJS `<select>` Directive API Reference - Using `ngRepeat` to generate `select` options](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select#using-ngrepeat-to-generate-select-options).

Answer (score 0):

I was able to detect the following problems (which is already pointed out in the comments):

1. Your `$scope.selections` array has only one item. You need to format in a differet way. Like this: `[{ code: 1, name: "Option1"}, { code: 2, name: "Option 2" }]`;
2. The correct syntax for `ng-repeat` is: `item in array`.

Changed that and some other adjustments resulted in the source below:

```js
angular.module('MyApp', ['ngMaterial'])
    .controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope) {
        $scope.Parent_Data = [{Name:"Bob", Selection: 1 },{Name:"Rick", Selection: 2}, {Name:"Lori", Selection: 3}];
        $scope.selections = [{ code: 1, name: "Option1"}, { code: 2, name: "Option 2" }, { code: 3, name: "Option 3" }, { code: 4, name: "Option 4" }, { code: 5, name: "Option 5" }]
    });
```

```html
<html ng-app="MyApp">

<head>
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-material/1.2.5/angular-material.min.css"
        rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
    <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
        <div ng-repeat="parent in Parent_Data">
            <md-input-container>
                <label>{{ parent.Name }}</label>
                <md-select ng-model="parent.Selection">
                <md-option ng-repeat="item in selections" ng-value="item.code"> {{item.name}} </md-option>
                </md-select>
            </md-input-container>   
        </div>
        
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.8.3/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-animate/1.8.3/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-aria/1.8.3/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-material/1.2.5/angular-material.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```